# mapping containers to docker host's /etc/hosts automatically with the same port for each container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a basic docker-compose setup consisting of the following:

- docker bridge subnet starting at 192.168.50.0/24
- 4 services: rabbit, spring-config, fares, checkin
- each of of these services has its hostname correctly set and are able to find each other from within the subnet (192.168.50.0). Ips are dynamically attributed in this subnet, and they all start on port 8080 within their respective containers.
- From the host, the bridge network is visible and each instance of the container is accessible using its ip.

I cannot manage to resolve these host entries without mapping a different port than 8080 to the docker host.

For this entry in my host's /etc/hosts:
192.168.50.1 fares rabbit config book checkin: the services are only accessible if I explicitely bind the services' ports 8080 to my host's port 8081, port 8082, port 8083... for each service in the .yml file.

Is there another way to make sure the services are discoverable by their dns name even from outside of the subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind all 4 containers to the same port on the host. Only one container per port. But there are some workarounds:

### Option 1: Use Different Ports for Each Container

- For exmaple, bind ports 8081, 8082, 8083, and 8084.
- In /etc/hosts, map each containers IP correctly.
- Specify the port in addition to the hostname when connecting. Like `https://fares:8081`

Your /etc/hosts might look like this:

```
192.168.50.1 fares
192.168.50.2 rabbit
...
```

### Option 2: Use a Reverse Proxy

You can set up an *additional* Docker container as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) in your docker-compose.yml. The reverse proxy container can bind to port 8080 and forward the request to the correct container depending on the hostname. You don't need to bind ports from the other containers on the host because your reverse proxy is forwarding the requests. There's a blog post that explains how this works in detail: http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

Comment: Ok I think I'll setup static ips for each container within the subnet and work gradually from there.